# Who was the Scottish philosopher that came up with the idea of a Scottish militia?

Tags: political-history, social-history

I read a book on the Scottish Enlightenment a couple of weeks ago and am trying to remember the name of the Scottish Philosopher that feared the ideas of a polite society would weaken the British people and a militia was required to bring some of their less civilized nature back as a balance was necessary for a modern society between the uncivilized and the civilized. I remember thinking the idea was interesting as it is something I can see occurring in the world today, and a little ironic because this idea came right at the end of an era of British history were they had all but removed one of the last remaining warrior societies in Europe, the Highlanders and imposed the first of the disarming acts upon the region. I would like to look into the philosophy further but can't remember the name of this particular thinker as he was merely little more than an aside in the book I read.

Comment: You might be thinking of [David Hume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hume) who _may_ have been the author of the satirical pamphlet [Sister Peg](https://archive.org/details/sisterpeg00adam).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question - the question is about a putative Scottish militia, but the reference is to British society.  The concept of a militia is not novel and wouldn't require a specifically Scottish philosopher.  Can you give us some context in time or in history?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'm assuming the context here is the [Scottish Militia Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Militia_Bill).  Famous for being the last bill to have been refused royal assent by the British monarch.

Comment: Much of what OP has stated in context  is true of the entire period of [_Scottish englightenment_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Enlightenment), on the issue/need for martial society. So, it would be true of Carlyle, Hume,  Smith and others. If one particular person is needed, I suppose it would be [**_Andrew 
 Fletcher of Saltoun_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Fletcher_(patriot)). Apologies if this is the answer OP seeks, _cf._ Robertson's (1985) [book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15002628-the-scottish-enlightenment-and-the-militia-issue).